# base point in Heegaard Floer homology

Tags: reference-request, 3-manifolds, heegaard-floer-homology

It is stated in Mcduff's overview paper "FLOER THEORY AND LOW DIMENSIONAL TOPOLOGY", end of page 9, that the Heegaard Floer homology without considering a base point depends only on the homology of the underlying 3-manifold.

Can anyone tell me in detail how it depends on the homology of the 3-manifold, or show me some references?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 6):

McDuff states that she's assuming throughout that she's dealing with rational homology spheres only (i.e. finite $H_1$), which simplifies the answer to your question a great deal. Also, for the sake of simplicity I will only consider coefficients in $\mathbb{F}=\mathbb{F}_2$ (the field with two elements).

"Ignoring the basepoint" can be translated into algebra by saying "set $U=1$" (in all theories except the hat, where there's no $U$): this has the effect of working on the chain complex $\widehat{CF}$ but with a lot more differentials than $\widehat{\partial}$ normally counts.

Except that now we have a nice algebraic version of dealing with this, and one just needs to take the tensor product with $R = \mathbb{F}[U]/(U-1)\cong \mathbb{F}$, and when we're working over $\mathbb{F}$ the algebra is much kinder. In particular, this new version of $HF$ will be $HF^+(Y)\otimes R = HF^-(Y)\otimes R$.

Since, for rational homology spheres, $HF^\pm$ is simply one tower plus torsion *in each spin$^c$ structure*, and since tensoring with $R$ kills the torsion, what you're left with is simply a copy of $\mathbb{F}$ for each spin$^c$ structure.

For 3-manifolds with $b_1>0$ the situation is slightly more complicated, and I think it's now proven (at least using the isomorphism with Seiberg-Witten) that this new version only sees (co)homological data, but you have to take into account the triple cup product $H^1\otimes H^1\otimes H^1 \to H^3$. E.g., for $T^3$ I would expect that ignoring the basepoint you get $\mathbb{F}^6$, while for $\#^3(S^1\times S^2)$ (which has the same $H_1$ as $T^3$) you get $\mathbb{F}^8$.

Comment: Thank you Marco, your reply exactly answered my question. For the case that the first betti number is non-zero, Danny (see below) showed me the references. So for non-torsion spin-c structures, the infinity-version is zero, and for torsion ones, it is given by the "cup homology".

Answer (score 3):

The Heegaard Floer version was carried out by Tye Lidman; see On the infinity flavor of Heegaard Floer homology and the integral cohomology ring. Comment. Math. Helv. 88 (2013), no. 4, 875–898, and [Heegaard Floer Homology and Triple Cup Products](http://arxiv.org/abs/1011.4277). Lidman proves that $HF^\infty(Y,s)$ is given by the `cup homology' introduced by Tom Mark (Triple products and cohomological invariants for closed 3-manifolds. Michigan Math. J. 56 (2008), no. 2, 265–281).

Comment: Danny, thank you for your references.